# Is there a source for structured product statistics?

Tags: reference-request

Is there a source giving statistics for structured products by type, number of issuances, location, etc.?

Thank you

Comment: You can try https://www.structuredretailproducts.com/ but I'm almost sure it's paid data.

Answer (score 3):

See https://www.sifma.org/resources/archive/research/statistics/ for a US-centric view that's regularly updated and is free of charge. It may not be granular enough for your needs.